# Using Object class as wrapper for input in spring boot RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am bit new to spring boot and I am trying to design a search on user history which will provide 3 attributes to search user history {userId, searchKey, SearchValue}.

The search value datatype may differ based on search.

> E.g
>
> 1. Userid=100, SearchKey=userAddress, searchValue='10 Downing Street'
> 2. Userid=100, SearchKey=external, searchValue=true
> 3. Userid=100, SearchKey=companyId, searchValue=25

I am trying to design a rest endpoint as below. This endpoint will integrate with react front end.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/searchUserHistoryByKeyValue")
public ResponseEntity<Object> searchUserHistoryByKeyValue(
      @RequestParam(value = "userId") int userId,
      @RequestParam(value = "searchKey") String searchKey,
      @RequestBody Object searchValue) {

          List<org.json.simple.JSONObject> entities =
              userHistoryService.searchUserHisotryByKeyValue(userId, searchKey, searchValue);
          return new ResponseEntity<>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have implemented a dynamodb search on userhistory object which takes input as generic searchValue object as search filter as below.
Dynamo DB Querying - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dynamodb/dynamodb_querying.htm

```
 public List<JSONObject> searchUserHistoryByKeyValue(
      int userId, String searchKey, Object searchValue) throws DataAccessException {

  Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(userHistoryTable.getName());

  Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames =
      DEFAULT_USER_FILTERS.stream()
          .collect(
              Collectors.toMap(attrib -> attrib, attrib -> attrib.substring(1), (a, b) -> b));

Optional<String> projectionExpression =
          createProjectionExpression(
              Collections.singletonList(searchKey), expressionAttributeNames);

      Optional<String> filterProjectionExpression =
          buildCustomProjectionExpression(
              Collections.singletonList(searchKey), expressionAttributeNames);

      QuerySpec querySpec =
          new QuerySpec()
              .withProjectionExpression(projectionExpression.orElse(StringUtils.EMPTY))
              .withKeyConditionExpression("#userId = :userId")
              .withFilterExpression(
                  String.format(
                      "%s = :searchValue",
                      filterProjectionExpression.orElseThrow(
                          () -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Search Attributes"))))
              .withNameMap(expressionAttributeNames)
              .withValueMap(Map.of(":userId", userId, ":searchValue", searchValue))
              .withScanIndexForward(false);
```

When I am trying use swagger or postman to test this endpoint , I am not able to pass in
*@RequestBody Object searchValue* . it just shows as empty braces - {}

[image]

Also it shows below error as -

> 'TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with
> GET/HEAD method cannot have body. '

I am not able to make this work? Appreciate your insights on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's HTTP protocol.
You cannot pass any body object with the Get method. You have to use Post or Put method for using a body in HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestBody` not for single value it is intended for your custom object that is used with POST or PUT but in you case you can `@RequestParam` also if `@RequestParam` take attribute required with boolean vlue which tell your endpoint caller which params is optional if you set it False and which is required if you set it True